# Query contar los INSERT de un mes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Deseo contar los INSERT realizados en un mes, para eso al momento de INSERT tengo un campo llamado fecha `$fecha=date("n/Y");` pero deseo contar cuantos INSERT hice en esa fecha, para después mostrarlo en un gráfico con Morris.JS `X seria la el mes y año`  e  `y seria la suma de insert de esa fecha`.
Tengo el siguiente código

```js
<script>
new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  data: [
    <?php echo $chart_data ?>
  ],
  // x fecha de  ingreso.
  xkey: 'fecha',
  // y contar los datos de ingreso de tal fecha.
  ykeys: [''],
  labels: ['Ingresados']
});
</script>
```

```css
    SELECT DISTINCT (fecha)
    FROM trabajador 
    WHERE fecha 
    IN (SELECT fecha 
    FROM trabajador 
GROUP BY fecha 
HAVING count( fecha ) >0) 
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

```html
<?php 
//index.php
include('include/conexion.php');
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT (fecha) FROM trabajador WHERE fecha IN (SELECT fecha FROM trabajador GROUP BY fecha HAVING count( fecha ) >0) ORDER BY fecha DESC;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $chart_data .= "{ fecha:'".$row["fecha"]."'}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
```

mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al ejecutar deseo saber

-09/2017 ,1
-11/2017 ,1
-10/2017 ,3

Comment: tu campo fecha en la base de datos que tipo es?

Comment: varchar lo guardo de la siguiente forma date("n/Y");

Comment: y por qué no mejor guardarlos como date y hacer un group by MONTH(fecha)?

Comment: como quedaría la query ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se podría hacer de esta manera, pero no sé si funcione con el motor de base de datos que esté utilizando, pero básicamente es lo que tienen que hacer:

```
     SELECT YEAR(fecha) AS anio, MONTH(fecha) AS mes, COUNT(*) AS                   
     cantidad_registros
     FROM trabajador 
     GROUP BY 1,2
     ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Comment: Me cuenta los registros pero en total, deseo saber los registros ingresado totales en tal mes.

Comment: Con la instruccion WITH ROLLUP vas a poder obtener el acumulado   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

tenemos que convertir la cadena en una fecha que se pueda ordenar

SELECT 
date(concat_ws('-',SUBSTRING(fecha,4),SUBSTRING(fecha,1,2),'01')) as f
,count( f ) as c
    FROM trabajador 
GROUP BY f 
HAVING c > 0
ORDER BY fecha DESC;